# Getting a JSON key as column with node mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, mysql2

Try to make the following SQL query using the node [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) package:

```sql
SELECT name, someObject->>"$.foo" as slice
FROM someTable;
```

The table `someTable` has 2 columns: `name`, a varchar; and `someObject`, a [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) column.

Imagine at least one row exists like this:

```
name      someObject
==========================
John      { "foo": "bar" }
```

The expected result of the query is:

```
name      slice
==========================
John      bar
```

Simply doing this works:

```
const result = await connection.query('SELECT name, someObject->>"$.foo" as slice FROM someTable');
```

However, I need the `foo` value escaped as it is user input. How to properly escape this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the question, I figured out the answer. Hopefully this can be helpful to others.

Considering the column / slice string: `someObject->>"$.foo"`

The answer is: Treat the column portion (`someObject`) as a column, and treat the string portion (`$.foo`) as a string.

So to escape it properly do this:

```
const columnName = "someObject";
const sliceName = "$.foo";

const sql = 'SELECT name, ??->>? as slice FROM someTable';
const values = [columnName, sliceName];
const result = await connection.query(sql, values);
```